# launching C# functions from the JavaScript in the application (not using the asp)

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to execute C sharp function from a Java based web portal so I can execute the functions back in the app

I would like to make an application that uses a webpage to call the functions on the application

for example I have a button on the website im viewing from the C sharp application I would like to make that button execute a function in the C sharp application so that way I can easily manage my UI from a website

Comment: You can't call C# or any other language from a website (client side).  You could from Node.js,  but then thats something different.

Answer (score 0):

you can call backend method with ajax call or try edge.js it's node base framework.
http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/